# My boot drive says there is less space than actual

Tags: boot

my /boot drive is on a separate 250 MB partition and the file manager shows only 31MB are in the /boot folder.

```
hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ ls -lah /boot
total 31M
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 3.0K Feb 26 21:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4.0K Feb 26 20:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2M Jan 13 15:12 abi-3.13.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 162K Jan 13 15:12 config-3.13.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 1.0K Feb 26 23:03 extlinux
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1.0K Feb 26 21:22 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  20M Feb 26 20:36 initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
drwx------  2 root root  12K Oct  4 14:36 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 173K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 174K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 175K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3.3M Jan 13 15:12 System.map-3.13.0-45-generic
drwx------  4 root root 1.0K Jan 21 11:57 .Trash-0
-rw-------  1 root root 5.6M Jan 13 15:12 vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
```

However the system is saying my drive is 84% full. What is going on?

```
df -l
    Filesystem                      1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/peppermint--vg-root 237929104 12973716 212846180   6% /
    none                                    4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev                              1008136        4   1008132   1% /dev
    tmpfs                              203900     1032    202868   1% /run
    none                                 5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
    none                              1019488    10772   1008716   2% /run/shm
    none                               102400        8    102392   1% /run/user
    /dev/sda1                          240972   191733     36798  84% /boot
```

I have nothing left to purge out of my boot folder. I've gotten rid of all the old kernels and packages I can. There is an invisible chunk of drive space occupied and I have no idea how to get this space back. any ideas what's happening here?

here are my inodes, does this look normal?

```
hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ df -i
Filesystem                        Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/peppermint--vg-root 15122432 182403 14940029    2% /
none                              254872      2   254870    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                              252034    486   251548    1% /dev
tmpfs                             254872    474   254398    1% /run
none                              254872      2   254870    1% /run/lock
none                              254872     69   254803    1% /run/shm
none                              254872      9   254863    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                          62248    376    61872    1% /boot
```

My current kernel...

```
hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ uname -a
Linux hab-AOD255 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try `du -chd 0 /boot`. What does that show?

Comment: `code` hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ du -chd 0 /boot
du: cannot read directory ‘/boot/.Trash-0’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘/boot/lost+found’: Permission denied
38M /boot
38M total
`code`

Comment: Add a sudo before that, I think your mystery files are located under lost+found or .Trash-0.

Comment: `186M /boot
186M total`

Comment: There you are! Mystery files in either .Trash-0 or lost+found. Do  `sudo su` and go in and delete them. lost+found is used for corrupted files recovered when checking the disk on startup, .Trash-0 is a trash folder for, I think, root.

Comment: `hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ ls -as /boot
total 30841
    3 .                                12 lost+found
    4 ..                              174 memtest86+.bin
 1144 abi-3.13.0-45-generic           175 memtest86+.elf
  163 config-3.13.0-45-generic        176 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
    1 extlinux                       3324 System.map-3.13.0-45-generic
    1 grub                              1 .Trash-0
19961 initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic   5702 vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic`

Comment: See my answer, most of your files are in the hidden system folders .Trash-0 or lost+found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the actual space a partition or a file takes on the disk use `du` command. For example:

```
du -sh /boot  ##Will show the actual size on the disk /boot takes
du -sh /boot/grub/  ##Will show the actual size on the disk /boot/grub takes
```

The output `ls -lah /boot` needs some explanations:

1. Its basically show the literal file size. For example if a text file is 700 Bytes then it will show 700 bytes as the file size but e.g. in ext4 filesystem a file takes 4K space at minimum (block size) on the disk. So, `ls` is not showing what disk stores.
2. `ls` will show the directory entries as the block size your filesystem has (this is happening in your case), but actually the directory can contain files/directories having the size of MB/GB range. To get the actual size of a directory on disk use `du` command.

See [`man du`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/du.1.html) for more info.

Comment: `hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ sudo du -sh /boot
186M /boot` 

`hab@hab-AOD255 ~ $ sudo du -sh /boot/grub
6.7M /boot/grub`

Comment: @Ken: please check my edits on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap this up, using `sudo du -chd 0 /boot` you can tell the size of the files in there. You can also do `sudo du -chd 1 /boot` to see which folders are taking the most space. Use `sudo su` to become root and remove the files (BE CAREFUL!!!!).

While in as root, do `ls -lA` to see all files in there. `cd` into lost+found and do the same `ls -lA` to find any files in there.

Comment: ok. so the mystery files are in the trash. but how do i get in there to clear this? using sudo du -chd 1 /boot` shows `148M /boot/.Trash-0` -- that's the culprit right there. thanks!

Comment: hab-AOD255 .Trash-0 # ls -la
total 8
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Jan 21 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 3072 Feb 26 21:22 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Jan 21 11:58 files
drwx------ 2 root root 3072 Jan 21 11:58 info

Comment: used `rm -rf` in Trash-0 and seemed to do the trick. Thanks @Zzzach...

Comment: You're very welcome! Feel free to mark this thread solved.